pyperclip not working on ubuntu 22.04 server
When I was running my install requirement.txt file I got:
Warning Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pipfile, since package 'wheel' is not installed
Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system

Uninstalled it:
pip uninstall pyperclip

As suggested here
https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/5478 I tried:
pip install pyperclip --use-pep517

And
pip install wheel
pip install pyperclip

Tried both solutions at different times, no more warning
Then when using my webapp I was getting this error:
Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system

Went to this page
https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error
Tried
sudo apt-get install xsel
uninstall
sudo apt-get install xclip
uninstall
pip install PyQt5 and PyQt6
uninstall

Tried a combo of
sudo apt-get install xsel
pip install PyQt5

None of them worked
This is beyond me, was hoping just by adding this commands it would resolve it but feels like something is missing, like the packages are not communicating.
On my template I have a submit input tag.
This runs a function on my view that parses the user's table and generates a text, I want to use pyperclip to copy this text to the user's clipboard.
As a good noob I want to say, 'It runs on my machine', my problem is when pushing it to the server. Am I supposed to install pyperclip directly on the server instead of on my virtual environment?
Can I use pyperclip with my webapp, send the user a text to clipboard, so the user can paste it somewhere else? Does pyperclip only works locally?
Thanks in advance

If you look at the git repo for pyperclip ... it hasn't had any updates in 3 years.  I would say that using it in a new project is probably a bad idea.  (But the author did provide a Patreon link ...)
